# visual studio 2022 debugger not showing Qt values

Tags: qt, visual-studio-2022

by default visual studio debugger does not show QString, QByteArray or similar data type values. by searching I found out that I should install Qt vs tools and it will create a .natvis file which will help Visual Studio to show these values. after installing it on VS 2022, the debugger shows those values, but only on simple variables. I mean if you hover on an object that has a QString member, the value of that QString is not shown and only a memory address is shown. I did not have this problem on VS 2019.

here is a simple example to know what I mean.

```cpp
class testclass
{
public:
    QString testString;
    testclass(QString v)
    {
        testString = v;
    }
};

void testFunc()
{
    testclass* obj= new testclass("123"); //debugger does not show value of testString when expanding obj value
    auto string= obj->testString; // does show value of string.
}
```

also the qt5.natvis file on VS 2019 and the one On VS 2022 are the same.

Answer (score 1):

After installing [Qt VS Tools for Visual Studio 2022](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=TheQtCompany.QtVisualStudioTools2022) i was able to see a human readable string in QString objects while debugging.
Neither did i bother to set them up nor do I know if these tools generated a .nativs file.